# Swift Subtracting Double gives weird results

Tags: swift, double, subtraction

Swift subtracting floating point or double values gives wrong answer

for example

0.45 - 0.34 = 0.10999999

I want it to give exactly two decimal point results Just like my inputs.

Comment: Don't you mean `0.45 - 0.34 = 0.10999999999999999` instead of 0.11?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: @Dave you need to use decimal type and make sure to use the string initializer `Decimal(string: "0.45")! - Decimal(string: "0.34")!  // 0.11`